# Parse xml and apply formating to text

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight, formatting

I am storing some text in a XML file and want to display it in my application by applying the formating to the text in a RichTextBox or something similar (maybe it would be better to have it as a listbox too?)

it would be something like this

```
<Text> 
  <Normal> This is some <Bold> text </Bold> which i like to put somewhere </Normal>
  <Bold><Italic> But there is a problem </Italic></Bold>
  <Normal> I don't know how </Normal>
</Text>
```

this text would look like this

This is some **text** which i like to put somewhere
***But there is a problem***
I don't know how

I have searched the net but didnt find any solution...

Edit: I forgot to say that I am developing a silverlight navigation application so i cant user flowdocuments:/

Comment: You should probably take a look at FlowDocuments (WPF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to manually go through the XML nodes and define what should happen for each node.  There's many different ways to implement something like that, but I'd start by keeping it simple.

For example: (pseudocode)

```
Foreach XMLnode node in xmlnodes
{
    if (node.attribute == "bold")
    {
        // apply bold to node text
    }
}
```

You can do it like this, which is fairly simple.  I'm sure there is many ways to improve upon it and it can get fairly complicated I'm sure.

Comment: if statements aren't slow... write and test it first, then judge whether or not it is slow

Comment: still, you need to write it and test it first, before optimizing